# Read a txt/sql file as formatted string - f'{}' in Python

Tags: python, sql

I have sql file which has table names as formatted string

**query.sql**

```
SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE LOAD_DT = '{load_date}'
```

How to read the sql file as f-string to pass it to `pd.read_sql()` method?

```
table_name = PRODUCTS
load_date = '15-08-2020'
# n other local variables

with open('query.sql','r') as file:
    sql_str = file.read()
```

**Note**: I do not prefer **.format(table_name,load_date)** or .format(**locals()) as I have a custom function to read various sql files and don't want to send a param list of format variables every time, the reason being if the format list is huge it will be laborious while preparing the sql file with positional arguments and chances of mistakes are high

Comment: It should be mentioned that this method of query generation introduces a heavy security risk into the application.  Perhaps consider researching stored procedures, or parameterised queries instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method of string:

```
sql_str = "SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE LOAD_DT = '{load_date}'"
sql_str.format(table_name="PRODUCTS", load_date="15-08-2020")
```

You can also pass all local variables into the `.format` method:

```
table_name = "PRODUCTS"
load_date = "15-08-2020"
sql_str.format(**locals())
```

It is also possible to achieve desired result using `eval`, which is quite dangerous:

```
table_name = "PRODUCTS"
load_date = "15-08-2020"
sql_str = "SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE LOAD_DT = '{load_date}'"
sql_str_f = f"f\"{sql_str}\""
result = eval(sql_str_f)
```

Comment: I don't prefer this method as I have a custom function to read sqls and don't wanna send a param list of format string variables everytime

Comment: Maybe `a.format(**locals())` will do the trick? It will pass all local variables to the `format` method

Comment: I do not prefer sql_str.format() as I have a custom function to read various sql files and don't want to send a param list of format variables every time because it will be laborious while preparing the sql file with positional args if the locals() list is huge

Comment: I've added one more option using `eval`, perhaps it will suit you.

Comment: perfect :) but can you kindly explain why eval is dangerous/ not a conventional way despite the expected result?

Comment: `eval` executes code, which is passed into that function. So if someone passes some real python code into your function, then that code will be executed. Theoretically, anything can be executed from that code.